# Animating change class state using ngClass

Tags: angular, angular-material, css-animations

I have a material sidenav, that is open at first and by clicking the menu item it becomes extended. I do it by using 2 classes and use ngClass to move between expanded class and non expanded one:

**HTML**:

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container" hasBackdrop="false">
  <mat-sidenav #sidenav class="sidenav" mode="over" opened="true">
    <mat-list-item (click)="isExpanded = !isExpanded">
      <div [ngClass]="{'list-item-expanded': isExpanded , 'list-item': !isExpanded}">
        <div class="icon-container">
          <i class="icon-hamberger-menu"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="title-container">{{'menu.menu'| translate }}</div>
      </div>
    </mat-list-item>
    <mat-list-item>
      <div [ngClass]="{'list-item-expanded': isExpanded , 'list-item': !isExpanded}">
        <div class="icon-container">
          <i class="icon-dashboard"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="title-container">{{'menu.dashboard'| translate }}</div>
      </div>
    </mat-list-item>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <div class="page-content">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

**my 2 scss classes**:

```
.sidenav {
    .list-item {
      cursor: pointer;
      display: flex;
      min-width: 64px;
      height: 64px;
      justify-content: center;
      flex-direction: column;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .list-item-expanded {
      cursor: pointer;
      min-width: 200px;
      height: 64px;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: space-between;
      padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
    }
  }
```

**2 states**:

[image]
[image]

Is there any way to make them **animating** from open state to expanded state?

Comment: Maybe using `ViewChild()` and animating with js.

Comment: @VahidNajafi thank you, i made it by css animations.

Comment: Hi @FatemeFazli I'm trying to achieve your exact result, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

used `mat-expansion-panel "opens" with angular enter-leave animations, although current state is closed.`

Comment: thank you but i don't want to use mat-expansion-panel.

Answer (score 0):

Add "transition: all 0.3s" in sidenav class.

Comment: This could be a comment, else elaborate on the context on such properties that would help to understand.